# Returning Mysql result with COUNT( * )

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to return a count from mysql. My code is below

```
$number_of_options_sql = tep_db_query("SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM 
(select sum(options_id) as total from products_attributes 
where products_id='".$products_id."' group by options_id) as total");
$number_of_options_result = tep_db_fetch_array($number_of_options_sql);
```

When I run this query in Phpmyadmin, it shows the result with `COUNT(*)` at the table heading. I'm getting the correct result, the query works for me, I just can't print it out on the screen.

I've tried returning the value the following ways and neither print anything on the screen:

```
echo $number_of_options_result[COUNT( * )];
echo $number_of_options_result[total];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is assigning an alias to the table/query not the column. use this one below:

```
$number_of_options_sql = tep_db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM (select sum(options_id) as total from products_attributes where products_id='".$products_id."' group by options_id) a");
$number_of_options_result = tep_db_fetch_array($number_of_options_sql);
```

Also looks like you want to know count of distinct options id for a product_id, I would rewrite the query as follows:

```
$number_of_options_sql = tep_db_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT options_id) as total FROM  products_attributes WHERE products_id='".$products_id."'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `AS field_name` after `COUNT(*)`

```
$number_of_options_sql = tep_db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS field_name FROM (select sum(options_id) as total from products_attributes where products_id='".$products_id."' group by options_id) as total");
```

To print:

```
echo $number_of_options_result['field_name'];
```

(Replace "field_name" with any relevant name of your choice)

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your query to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ....
```

then it will be stored like 'count' and you can print it the $number_of_options_result[count]; way.

Answer (score 0):

put in a variable "total"

```
$number_of_options_sql = tep_db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total
```

then it works

```
echo $number_of_options_result['total'];
```